# Python: Read data file and work on process/filter the data

Tags: python-3.x

I have recently started learning Python and trying to grab the concepts and meanwhile got a sample data file for 30K rows as below , separated by spaces.

```
P160543 East Asia and Pacific   IN  C   
P166720 Africa  IN  N   
P165276 East Asia and Pacific   AD  n   IIST
P159835 Latin America and Caribbean LA  B   
P160778 Latin America and Caribbean LA  B   
P164290 South Asia  AS  N   
P165493 South Asia  SA  N   
P165585 Latin America and Caribbean LAC N   
P157987 South Asia  SA  C   ALAESH
P158364 South Asia  SAS B   EPATET
```

1. Need to skip the rows where a row contains 'N' or 'n' in column 4:
2. Now read each line and save values of column in variables
3. Specify a search if Typest = 'IN' then return values as  RegionName
   ='East Asia and Pacific' and 'Africa' and id = P160543,P166720

if colum 3= 'AD' then return values from column 2 = 'East Asia and Pacific'  and id = P165276
if colum 3= 'LAC' then return values Latin America and Caribbean

I don't have Numpy and others libraries to use ... want to get this done with with file concepts.

I know to read the files and display the contents of file, removing blank lines and skipping the comments line, but stuck on said problem.

Please advice.

Comment: Removed the column header... just realized file has no heading rows

Comment: FYI (other people answering):
header_line = "id    RegionName    TypeSt    TypePD    TypeCode"

Answer (score 0):

Create a generator to loop through the lines of your file
grab the header from the first line of the file

```
def read_file(fullname):
    with open(fullname) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield header_line, line
```

---

```
myFile = read_file(r"Path/To/Your/File")
header_line = "id    RegionName    TypeSt    TypePD    TypeCode"

for line in myFile:
    data = dict(zip(header.split("\t"), line.split("\t")))

    # Here's a dictionary of the data for the current row
    # You can access the elements of the row by name as follows in the filter example:

    if data["TypePD"].lower() == "N":
        continue
    .....
```

---

That ought to be enough to get you started since this smells like a homework assignment.

Be wary of anyone recommending pandas - I work in a big data environment, pandas doesn't work w/ multi-gig files/millions of records generators will.

Comment: Thanks Schalton. Sorry I have removed header rows from file... just realized file has no header row to identify columns name

Comment: You can remove the header index from the generator and set the header string or list outside of the loop.

Comment: This should be more than enough to get you going. If you're looking for a fully coded solution hop on fiverr :-D